# Adding Views dynamically from an Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, layout, android-recyclerview

I want to add comments like happens on facebook mobile... My code works for the first comment, but on the second it crashs. The error message shows that my array has just one element, I also tried initialize the array capacity, but I receive the same error.

So, here is my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            ArrayList<View> rootView = new ArrayList<View>();

            rootView.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_comment, null));
            FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.campoComentarios);

            container.addView(rootView.get(contadorComment));
            contadorComment++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to do that

You should make a RecyclerView and then create an adapter to it then add the elements to that adapter ....I know it's a bit hard but this is the correct way to do that ... for more details see this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGFvbvkZiMs

Comment: Thank You, I'll try this, but for now I'll check this question solved.